# Jstree use HTML link with <a>

Tags: javascript, php, jstree

I have made a simple folder structur with jstree.

Everything works fine so far, but I was wondering whether there is a simple way to use clickable hyperlinks within the tree through "a href=". 
When I double click on the folder/word itself the menu structure drops down, but with a single click the hyperlink in this case google.de doesn't work.
In fact nothing happens when you single click one the folders/words.

```
<div id="categorymenue">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="google.de">One</a>
     <ul>
     <li>Example 1</li>
     <li>Example 2
     <ul>
 <li>Example 1</li>
 <li>Expample 2</li>
 </ul></li></li></ul>
 <li>Two
     <ul>
 <li>Example 1</li>
 <li>Example 2</li>
 </ul></li>
 <li>Three
 <ul>
     <li>Example 1</li>
     <li>Example 2</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>JOKE</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: code please to be able to help

Comment: Doesn't feel all too useable. Perhaps use the 'contextmenu' or 'types' plugins could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<!-- 3 setup a container element -->
<div id="categorymenue">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://google.de">One</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Example 1</li>
                <li>Example 2
                    <ul>
                        <li>Example 1</li>
                        <li>Expample 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Two
            <ul>
                <li>Example 1</li>
                <li>Example 2</li>
            </ul>
    </li>
        <li>Three
            <ul>
                <li>Example 1</li>
                <li>Example 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>JOKE</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#categorymenue').jstree();


        var DELAY = 700, clicks = 0, timer = null;
        $("a").on("click", function (e) {
            clicks++;

            var _this = this;
            if (clicks === 1) {

                timer = setTimeout(function () {

                    if ($(_this).attr('href')) {
                        window.location = $(_this).attr('href');
                    }
                    clicks = 0;

                }, DELAY);

            } else {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                clicks = 0;
            }

        })
            .on("dblclick", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now on the first menu level. All sub-menu seem to not like the code. Any idea why? Could it be the different ID name? Otherwise I would try it with the same classes altogether

Comment: base HTML you posted was wrong in the nesting, now it's working! Please accept my answser if it's fit the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Looking at JSTree's docs, it clearly states that any custom markup you're adding is overwritten per default. [As the docs say](https://www.jstree.com/docs/html/):

> Internally jstree converts the text to a link, so if there already is
>   a link in the markup jstree won't mind. Like Child node 2. Clicking on
>   the link however will not direct the user to a new page, to do that -
>   intercept the changed.jstree event and act accordingly.

So, what this tells us is that whenever someone clicks an element, whether there be a link there or not, you need to toggle the node in question.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="jstree">
    <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#root_node_1">Root node 1
        <ul>
          <li id="child_node_2"><a href="#child_node_1">Child node 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#another_custom_anchor">Child node 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="root_node_2">Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

PS: *Pay attention to that the a-tag is wrapping the entire #root_node_1 element.*

JS:

```
$(function() {
    // Code here
    $('#jstree').jstree()
    $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
      $.jstree.reference('#jstree').toggle_node(data.selected);
      // Alternatively use open_node or close_node explicitly depending on whether it is open or closed.
    });
});
```

Here's a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr7xLx5k/25/

So, when you're clicking an href, what you're actually doing is calling the API with the node leaf telling it to reveal the contents of *that node*. It doesn't matter what the #href is.

It should be clear by now that this is battling with the plugin up to a point where one would argue and wonder whether to conform or switch (to a different plugin) alltogether.

Why do you need links?

---

[API](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=(&f=open_node(obj%20[,%20callback,%20animation])) references.

Comment: You are right it is really complicated but It does a really good folder structure job and I thought I could use it like a normal dopdown menu with hyperlinks too. Then it would do two things in one and everything I need

Comment: There are a number of built-in plugins if you need context menues on your list items.